# Qlabels getting clipped off at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I am trying to make a GUI for a piece of python code using PyQt.
However, the GUI seems to cut off the ends of two Qlabels for reasons I don't know. I have gone through other Questions on Stack Overflow for similar issues, but i did not find a fix for my specific problem.

Initially it was working fine. But after everything, I added a status bar to my the GUI and had to shift everything down by some amount. After i shifted everything, the text started to get cut off from the end. I did try reversing the process, but it did not help.

I am attaching a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Here is the complete code for the GUI:

```
import sys, os
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import FreqDist, word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from string import punctuation
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window(QMainWindow, QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(450, 450, 800, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Text Summarizer')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('summarize.png'))
        self.exit_text = 'Exited Application'
        self.file_open_button = None
        self.quit_button = None
        self.textbox_input = None
        self.textbox_output = None
        self.output_label = None
        self.input_label = None
        self.file_text = None
        self.my_output = None
        self.my_text = None
        self.summarize_button = None
        self.n = None
        self.no_lines = None
        self.line_no_input = None
        self.sent_no = None
        self.warning_text_1 = 'You have chosen summarization length more than the actual text length!\n' + \
                              'Please enter a valid number less than the length of actual text'

        self.home()


    # Used to anchor each element to edges with some offset (padding)
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        p = self.rect().bottomRight() - QPoint(20, 10) - self.quit_button.rect().bottomRight()
        self.quit_button.move(p)
        QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
        p = self.rect().bottomLeft() - QPoint(-20, 10) - self.file_open_button.rect().bottomLeft()
        self.file_open_button.move(p)
        QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
        p = self.rect().topRight() - QPoint(20, -60) - self.textbox_output.rect().topRight()
        self.textbox_output.move(p)
        QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
        p = self.rect().topRight() - QPoint(135, -25) - self.output_label.rect().topRight()
        self.output_label.move(p)
        QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)

    # Open file Function
    # Opens Dialog Box to open the file and select text
    # If file is of valid readable format, displays the contents on the left text box
    # Else throws a warning dialog box and prompts to either chose again else cancel
    def file_open(self):
        # noinspection PyBroadException
        try:
            name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File')
            file = open(name[0], 'r')
            self.file_text = file.read()
            self.sent_no = len(sent_tokenize(self.file_text))
            self.textbox_input.setPlainText(self.file_text)

            return self.file_text
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error Reported:', e)
            message_box = QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error!', 'File Open Error! Please Choose Valid File!',
                                              QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
            if message_box == QMessageBox.Ok:
                self.file_open()
            else:
                pass

    # Takes the input from the left textbox, summarize that and display on the right text box
    def summarize(self):
        # noinspection PyBroadException
        try:
            self.n = self.line_no_input.text()
            self.n = (int(self.n))
            if self.n > self.sent_no:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error!', self.warning_text_1,
                                    QMessageBox.Ok)
            else:
                self.my_text = self.textbox_input.toPlainText()
                self.my_output = self.text_summarize(self.my_text, no_lines=self.n)
                self.textbox_output.setPlainText(self.my_output)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error!', 'You have to input the text in the input textbox!\n'
                                                'You have to input a number in the number box!',
                                QMessageBox.Ok)

    # main function containing all the buttons and other elements to display
    def home(self):
        # The exit button on the right bottom corner
        self.quit_button = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.exit_application)
        self.quit_button.resize(self.quit_button.minimumSizeHint())

        # The File Open button on the left bottom corner
        self.file_open_button = QPushButton('Open File', self)
        self.file_open_button.clicked.connect(self.file_open)
        self.file_open_button.resize(self.file_open_button.minimumSizeHint())

        # The Summarize button on the left bottom corner
        self.summarize_button = QPushButton('Summarize', self)
        self.summarize_button.clicked.connect(self.summarize)
        self.summarize_button.resize(self.summarize_button.minimumSizeHint())
        self.summarize_button.move(365, 280)

        self.file_save_button = QPushButton('Save File', self)
        self.file_save_button.clicked.connect(self.file_save)
        self.file_save_button.resize(self.file_save_button.minimumSizeHint())
        self.file_save_button.move(365, 400)

        # Left Textbox element used to input the text to be summarized --- Editable
        self.textbox_input = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textbox_input.move(20, 65)
        self.textbox_input.resize(280, 395)

        # Right Textbox element used to display the output of the summarized text --- Not Editable (incomplete)
        self.textbox_output = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textbox_output.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textbox_output.move(340, 40)
        self.textbox_output.resize(280, 400)

        self.line_no_input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_no_input.move(430, 323)
        self.line_no_input.resize(30, 25)

        # Left Textbox heading label
        self.input_label = QLabel(self, text='Input Request')
        new_font = QFont("Arial", 16, QFont.Bold)
        self.input_label.setFont(new_font)
        self.input_label.move(95, 25)

        # Right Textbox heading label
        self.output_label = QLabel(self, text='Output Text')
        new_font = QFont("Arial", 16, QFont.Bold)
        self.output_label.setFont(new_font)

        self.no_lines = QLabel(self, text='Number of lines:')
        new_font = QFont("Arial", 10)
        self.no_lines.setFont(new_font)
        self.no_lines.move(330, 320)

        menu_open_file = QAction("&Open File", self)
        menu_open_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        menu_open_file.setStatusTip('Open from text file')
        menu_open_file.triggered.connect(self.file_open)

        menu_save_file = QAction("&Save File", self)
        menu_save_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        menu_save_file.setStatusTip('Save the out text')
        menu_save_file.triggered.connect(self.file_save)

        menu_exit = QAction("&Exit", self)
        menu_exit.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        menu_exit.setStatusTip('Exit the program')
        menu_exit.triggered.connect(self.exit_application)

        self.statusBar()

        main_menu = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = main_menu.addMenu('&File')
        file_menu.addAction(menu_open_file)
        file_menu.addAction(menu_save_file)
        file_menu.addAction(menu_exit)

        self.show()

    # Exit Definition. Runs when the app is Quit using the 'Quit' button
    def exit_application(self):
        print(self.exit_text)
        sys.exit()

    def selection_box(self):
        print('Inside selection_box')
        combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        for i in range(self.sent_no):
            item_text = str(i + 1) + ' Lines'
            combo_box.addItem(item_text)
        combo_box.move(365, 300)
        qApp.processEvents()

    def file_save(self):
        try:
            name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', '*.txt')
            file = open(name[0], 'w')
            text = self.textbox_output.toPlainText()
            file.write(text)
            file.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error!', "You don't have any text to save!",
                                QMessageBox.Ok)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    # GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have published an answer that solves your problem, on the other hand it is not necessary to indicate that you have removed, you only need to publish a [mcve], SO does not ask for your original code (here there are many users who belong to a company and must be confidential with the code), if not create a minimum code that can reproduce your error.

Comment: Why the heck don't you use the existing layout mechanisms instead of placing the widgets yourself at absolute sizes and positions?

Comment: How do i use that? I'm new to PyQt. If you can, then please answer with a better programmed code. This is all i could come up with by searching through documentation and tutorials and stack overflow. If there is a better method to do it then I'd like to know. I'm facing problems with padding and widget scaling. Like if i maximize or resize the window, nothing scales, they stay their respective small size. It's not dynamic. It's like a static window. I am trying to solve these one by one, it's been only 2 days that I've started with PyQt.

Comment: Have a look at [QLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html) and the classes that inherit from that (mainly QBoxLayout, QGridLayout, and QFormLayout).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the `QLabel` to fit the text then you must use `adjustSize()`, in your case:

```
self.input_label.adjustSize()
self.output_label.adjustSize()
```

**before:**

[image]

**after:**

[image]